# Is there an adapter (or other possibility) converting a SD card slot into an USB3.0 port?

Tags: sd-card, usb-3, raspberry-pi

Let's assume I would like to attach a USB3.0 external storage device to my Raspberry Pi by utilizing the SD card slot. Would that be feasible? 
(As far as I know the Ethernet is just a USB2.0 port in disguise, so that won't work. Not that there is any guarantee that the SD card speed would be higher.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to make that work. The best you can do is connect it to one of the USB ports. The Raspberry Pi simply doesn't provide any high-speed connections.